# Making program do two things at the same time and command crashes game

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am trying to make a alternate way to create "gravity" with python 2.7. I need the game to move the x position of the ball 25 pixels to the right AND the y position of the ball 25 pixels up. So here a piece of my current program:

```
    def jump(self):
        false = 0
        global false
        while self.rect.top < 750 and false == 0:
            self.rect.top += 50
            self.rect.left += 50
        while self.rect.top <= 750:
            false = 1
            self.rect.top -= 50
            self.rect.left += 50
```

First, how do I make the program do the lines 5 and 6/ 9 and 10 at the same time? My next question will need this source code:

```
import pygame, sys
import time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1500,750])
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill([255, 255, 255])


class Attacker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

    def jump(self):
        false = 0
        global false
        while self.rect.top < 750 and false == 0:
            self.rect.top += 50
            self.rect.left += 50
        while self.rect.top <= 750:
            false = 1
            self.rect.top -= 50
            self.rect.left += 50

my_ball = Attacker('wackyball.bmp', [300, 300])

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
    screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            my_ball.rect.top = my_ball.rect.top - 200
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            my_ball.rect.top = my_ball.rect.top + 125
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            my_ball.rect.left += 175
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            my_ball.rect.left -= 125
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            my_ball.jump()




screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

When ever I press the spacebar so my guy will "jump" (do the jump function), my game crashes. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game is crashing because it's getting inside the while loop and not returning.(inside the second while loop)

If you want to simulate gravity, you need to move the char a little bit every frame, the way you are doing you will move it all the way up, then all the way down in a single frame, meaning it won't appear to move.

Here's some ideas that might help you.

```
import pygame, sys
import time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1500,750])
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill([255, 255, 255])

class Attacker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x_pos, self.y_pos = location
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = location
        self.jumping = False
        self.falling = False
        self.direction = 1

    def jump(self):
        if self.y_pos > CEILING:
            self.x_pos += 1*self.direction
            self.y_pos -= 5
        else:
            self.jumping = False
            self.falling = True

        self.update_pos()

    def fall(self):
        if self.y_pos < FLOOR:
            self.x_pos += 1*self.direction
            self.y_pos += 5
        else:
            self.falling = False

        self.update_pos()

    def update_pos(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x_pos
        self.rect.y = self.y_pos

FLOOR = 700
CEILING = 300

my_ball = Attacker('wackyball.bmp',[300, FLOOR])


running = True
while running:
    if my_ball.jumping:
        my_ball.jump()
    if my_ball.falling:
        my_ball.fall()

    screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                my_ball.y_pos -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                my_ball.y_pos += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                my_ball.direction = 1
                my_ball.x_pos += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                my_ball.direction = -1
                my_ball.x_pos -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not my_ball.falling:
                    my_ball.jumping = True
            my_ball.update_pos()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It really does work! I made some adjustments to match my planned program. Thank you!